# Alert showing when the page is loaded when I only want onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a bookmarking system and when a image is bookmarked I want an alert with an image to confirm that a image is bookmarked.

I have a working alert and onclick it shows the alert. However, the alert also shows when the page is loaded. I can't figure out how to only show the alert when the form is submitted

The code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

          <!--form which sends field information to the database-->
          <form class="form" id="form" action="" method="post" >
            <img id="enlargedSymbol" type="text" size="60" name="pathOfSymbol" src='' /> <!--large symbol where source is inserted-->
                <br />
                <!--hidden input which value is set by query where then its sent to the database-->
                <input class="inputBox" type="hidden" name="pathOfSymbol" id="pathOfSymbol" />
                      <script>
                      var querySrc = URI(window.location.href).search(true).src; //gets image source
                      //sets image source as enlarged symbol
                      $("#enlargedSymbol").prop("src", querySrc);
                      //sets path of symbol as hidden value
                      $('#pathOfSymbol').val(querySrc);
                      </script>

                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="addToBookmarksButton" onclick="addedToBookmarks()"  >
                            <img id="addToBookmarksButton" src="img/addToBookmarks.png"  />
                        </button>


              </form>


              <script>
              $(function addedToBookmarks () {
                $("#dialog").dialog();
              });
              </script>

              <div id="dialog">
                <img src="img/addToBookmarks.png" alt="Placeholder Image" />
              </div>
```

Comment: Hide the dialog DIV initially.  Add code to show it in an OnSubmit() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
     $('#addToBookmarksButton').click(function(){
          $("#dialog").dialog();
     });
</script>
```